# Como eu faço para pegar informação das três primeiras linhas de uma table?

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela com varias linhas carregadas, porém preciso pegar informação das três primeiras linhas e armazenar em uma variável sem precisar usar a função `click`.Com essa informação armazenada em uma variável irei atribuir a um campo que vai carregar o gráfico, como faço isso  via script?

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML que tens?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente do que precisa, mas talvez possa começar com algo do tipo.

```
function le_tabela(linhas){
  var tabela = $("#tabela").find("tr");
  var matriz = new Array(linhas);
  for(var i=0;i<linhas;i++){
    var linha_tabela = tabela[i].childNodes;
    var tamanho = linha_tabela.length;
    var linha = new Array(tamanho);
    for(var j=0;j<tamanho;j++){
        linha[j] = linha_tabela[j].innerText;
    }
    matriz[i] = linha;
  }
    return matriz;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkgnddsj/